# How can I simulate a ViewCell in a TableSection with a Grid inside a StackLayout?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

My application calls two templates that create something similar to two ViewCells:

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="10">
   <template:DataGridTemplate Text="Updated" Label="{Binding Updated}" />
   <template:DataGridTemplate Text="Version" Label="{Binding Version}" />
</StackLayout>
```

Here's the template XAML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Grid Padding="20,0" xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Japanese;assembly=Japanese" 
      x:Class="Japanese.Templates.DataGridTemplate" 
      x:Name="this">
    <local:StyledLabel Text="{Binding Text, Source={x:Reference this}}" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
    <local:StyledLabel Text="{Binding Label, Source={x:Reference this}}" HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
</Grid>
```

I would like the height of the template to be 50 and also to have a line created between the two templates to simulate something like I would find in a ViewCell that's inside a TableSection.

Does anyone have any suggestions how I can do this? I tried setting the height of the Grid to 50 but it tells me that it's a read only property.

Comment: As you say, the [VisualElement.Height](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.visualelement.height?view=xamarin-forms) is read only, you'd want to set the [VisualElement.HeightRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.visualelement.heightrequest?view=xamarin-forms) property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**StackLayout**

```xaml
<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Padding="10" Spacing="0">
    <template:DataGridTemplate Text="Updated" Label="07/21/2018" />
    <template:DataGridTemplate Text="Version" Label="1.0.0" />
</StackLayout>
```

**DataGridTemplate**  (the line separator is in here, but could be added directly to the StackLayout instead)

```xaml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Grid Padding="20,0" HeightRequest="50" xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Sof2" 
      x:Class="Sof2.Templates.DataGridTemplate" 
      x:Name="this">

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <local:StyledLabel Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Text, Source={x:Reference this}}" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
    <local:StyledLabel Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Label, Source={x:Reference this}}" TextColor="Silver" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />

    <!-- Separator -->
    <BoxView Grid.ColumnSpan="2" BackgroundColor="Silver" HeightRequest="1" VerticalOptions="End" />

</Grid>
```

**Result**

[image]

If interactivity is needed, then you could add TapGestureRecognizers as appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Is there any advantage in using grid column definitions vs just setting Horizontal options? Also I see the first column definition doesn't have any size.  What does that mean?

Comment: The column definitions were used so that the 2 labels won't overlap if the text was really long (using only HorizontalOptions wouldn't prevent that but would be fine if the text is known to be short).  ColumnDefinitions have a default Width of * (GridUnitType.Star), which is a proportional weight.  The column definitions in the answer translate to, "Set column 1 to fit it's contents and then the remaining space is given to column 0."